# Solution to raise the amount of products( quotedetails or quoteproducts) in Quote entity via modal

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I want to add a `Button` in the `ribbon` of `Quote`,
When the user clicks on that, A **`modal`** displays, with two `fields`.
One is `quote product categories` that exist in that quote, that means it searches in quote product of the quote and find all the `categories` exist in that specific `quote` and then display them in a `combo box`. with their `guid` or something like that.
Another field is a textbox, which is `percentage`.
something like [image: this].
The `end-user` clicks on the ribbon button, the `modal` appears, he/she gives a number to the `percentage` and select one of the categories; when presses `apply` button, it find and return `all  amounts of the quote products` in that quote that matches the user selected category, `compute some amount based on quote total amount and the returned amounts` and  and `insert that computed number into a field` in each quote product named `overed_amount`.
How can I handle this? `JS or Plugin`?
I prefer to this via JS rather than writing plugin, But can I pass parameters between this HTML or JS file to CRM Form/Forms?
And does anybody have any sample? like this? any suggestion?
I googled and most of `Plugins` are about writing simple plugin based on existing code.
Can I display modal via `plugin`? Any suggestion or advise? or sample?

Answer (score 0):

Plugins (and custom workflow assemblies) run as part of the backend platform. The only "UI" component they have is they run synchronously and throws an Exception, a popup will show that Exception to the user.

The typical way to add custom UI components is via [custom web resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/webpage-html-web-resources).

In custom web resources you can do HTML / JS / CSS, and even leverage 3rd party libraries such as KendoUI. You can add them to the form or open them via a ribbon button.

A custom web resource can typically interact with the main Dynamics 365 form via the `parent` property (as the above linked article describes).

One library that can help with displaying custom web resources in D365 is [Alert.js](https://github.com/PaulNieuwelaar/alertjs), though as the documentation says, it's unsupported.

If you want to include some backend operations as part of the custom UI, you can create [custom actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/create-own-actions) and call them from the custom web resource's JavaScript.

Comment: @Arun : Sir,You mean I should create a UI with HTML/CSS and JS.
And then call a custom action.In my case, I need the quote product categories guid and name.
I should pass them from the quote to the custom html/css. ( as I see in your link,It accept these two fields )
Can I create A js function that do my work, and placed it in the CRM as web resource, call the JS function when press apply button on the HTML file and pass some parameter ( what user has selected and what precentage has entered ) to the form and that fucntion? In this way I can do this with no backend.

Comment: From within the custom web resource's JS you can query the system to get the information you want to display. Are you on v2011?

Comment: @Arun : Yes, Im on 2011 on-premise.

Comment: TY. Microsoft still has the 2011 SDK available for [download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24004).  It contains a bunch of sample code. You might want to look into using ...\SampleCode\JS\RESTEndpoint\JavaScriptRESTRetrieveMultiple\JavaScriptRESTRetrieveMultiple\Scripts\SDK.REST.js to help you retrieve data.